# Implement a two way caching on RAM and Hard Disk

Tags: ios, swift, caching, memory

In my app I made a http request from an api, I got a JSON with bunch of information and in that information I had urls from where I download images in my app , all stored in a array of class "UserInfo". Now I would like to cache the data stored in my array like this.Since I never done that stuff before I don't know how to approach this, I searched different topics and links but none of them was related to what I want to achieve, maybe someone here can point me in the right direction :

When the request is being made :

1. Check for the array in RAM, if it is there, grab it , else
2. Check for the array data in Hard Disk, if it is there, grab it, else
3. Make the http request and download everything.

Also I would like the expiration date for RAM to be 10 minutes, for Hard Disk 30.

I did read about NSCache and NSURLCache but I don't know how to obtain what I wrote above.

**EDIT :**

I solved the problem with saving on disk, now I have problems with NSCache.It always returns nil when I ask for my data. I'm coding in swift 3 and NSCache is a generic type that takes ObjectTypes key and value and I think there is a problem with my casting of values, in function load data it always skips the first if, any idea how to solve this ?.Code bellow:

```
private var users:[User] = [] // User is a class that implements NSCoding
private let ramCache = NSCache<NSString,NSArray>()

private var filePath:String{
    let manager = FileManager.default
    let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    return url!.appendingPathComponent("SavedData").path
}

private func saveData(user: User) { // this is called in function requestFromApi()
    self.users.append(user)
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(users, toFile: filePath)  // we save on disk
    ramCache.setObject(self.users as NSArray, forKey: "Data" as NSString)
   // print(self.users as NSArray)
}

private func loadData() {
    if let cachedVersion = ramCache.object(forKey: "Data" as NSString){ // this is null everytime
        // check if its on ram
        print("data was on ram")
        self.users = cachedVersion as! [User]
    }
    else if let savedUsers = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? [User] {
        // check if its on disk
        print("data was on disk")
        self.users = savedUsers
    } else {
        print("we requested the data")
        self.requestDataFromApi()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadData()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableViewCell")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking another look at URLCache. It has both RAM and disk-based caching. I typically increase the limits for each at app launch. With this approach, the caching limits specified in the response headers will be honored, so if those are not correct, you'll want to fix that too.

```
func initializeURLCache() {
    let memoryCapacity = 10 * 1024 * 1024 //  10 MB (up from default of 512 KB)
    let diskCapacity = 100 * 1024 * 1024  // 100 MB (up from default of 1 MB)
    let sharedCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: nil)

    URLCache.shared = sharedCache

    logger.info("Disk cache used \(URLCache.shared.currentDiskUsage) of \(URLCache.shared.diskCapacity)")
}
```

Comment: So when a file is larger than 10 MB it will be stored on disk, right? That's great but can I set manually the expire date for disk and ram caching?

Comment: URLCache takes care of deciding what is stored in RAM and what is stored on disk. It's transparent to you. As for expiration date, that is determined from the cache-related HTTP headers in the response. So if you do not have influence over those, this approach may not be what you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will wait to see if it is still another approach to my problem